# How to import worlds and characters

Tags: terraria

I had to switch accounts on my PC, but now when I go on to Terraria, my worlds and characters are all gone. I've no idea of how to put them back, but I do, however, have the files for my characters and worlds.

So how do you import a world and a character into Terraria?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the files on your PC's other account, then this should be relatively easy. First, you want to go back to your old account and locate your Terraria folder (this is often located in: Documents\My Games). Once you've found your Terraria folder, you can simply go into the "Players" and "Worlds" folders, and copy the player and World folders you want onto a flash drive. Once you've done this, all you have to do is the reverse process on the PC account you are now using.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Steam Cloud, you can easily upload your players and worlds like that. Alternatively, you could manually do it in case any issues arise with the Steam Cloud.

1. Go into File Explorer and locate your "Documents" folder.
2. Go to `Documents\My Games\Terraria` and you should see several files, but the only important ones are "Worlds" and "Players".
3. Save those to your Google Drive or other drive platform, or alternatively, use a flash drive to transport them. (WARNING: MAKE SURE TO MAKE A BACKUP IN THE EVENT OF ANY ERROR WITH TRANSFERRING CHARACTERS OR WORLDS.)
4. Finally, on your new computer, locate the `Documents\My Games\Terraria` file again and paste the files into the folder.